# I would like to export the contents of ios web view as html

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

I am writing an app for ios to extract information from a webpage, however, the relevant pieces on the page are built by javascript. So when it is loaded by webview, the javascript is executed and the information displays no problem. If I try to load the page into a string by using the following method, the javascript is loaded, but not actually executed, therefore the string has no useful data in it.

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Is there another way besides loading the page into webview and exporting it from there? If not, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's another way outside of letting the UIWebView execute the JS and render the page, but if you do end up going this route, you could just grab the HTML of the whole page and pass that to the native end like so:

`[dummyWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;"];`

Listening to the `window.load` event might be better to know when the page has finished going through all the JS

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Listening for window.load was a must.

Answer (score 0):

You set delegate to webView: `self.webView.delegate = self;` and implement UIWebViewDelegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
    NSLog(@"html1 = %@", html);
    // or use
    NSString *html2 = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
    NSLog(@"html2 = %@", html2);
}
```

Comment: I tried the the webViewDidFinishLoad, but even though the page was loaded, I don't think it waits for the javascript to finish executing.